# Optimizing SQL Query from a Big Table Ordered by Timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

We have a big table with the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `location_data` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `device_sn` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `data` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `gps_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lat` double(30,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` double(30,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dt` (`dt`),
  KEY `data` (`data`),
  KEY `device_sn` (`device_sn`,`data`,`dt`),
  KEY `device_sn_2` (`device_sn`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=721453698 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Many times we have performed query such as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM location_data WHERE device_sn = 'XXX' AND data = 'location' ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM location_data WHERE device_sn = 'XXX' AND data = 'location' AND dt >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00 ' AND dt <= '2014-01-01 23:00:00' ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

We have been optimizing this in a few ways:

1. By adding index and using `FORCE INDEX` on `device_sn`.
2. Separating the table into multiple tables based on the date (e.g. `location_data_20140101`) and pre-checking if there is a data based on certain date and we will pull that particular table alone. This table is created by cron once a day and the data in `location_data` for that particular date will be deleted.

The table `location_data` is HIGH WRITE and LOW READ.

However, few  times, the query is running really slow. I wonder if there are other methods / ways / restructure the data that allows us to read a data in sequential date manner based on a given `device_sn`.

Any tips are more than welcomed.

**EXPLAIN STATEMENT 1ST QUERY:**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys              | key       | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | location_dat | ref  | data,device_sn,device_sn_2 | device_sn | 50      | const,const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

**EXPLAIN STATEMENT 2nd QUERY:**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys                 | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_udp_new | range | dt,data,device_sn,device_sn_2 | dt   | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: `int(20)` for PK makes no sense. Indexes with low cardinality make no sense either. There is no `EXPLAIN` included. You're also using MyISAM, and if it's high write it's questionable how well it performs (you can't even control huge flushes to disk because of the engine). Forcing an index with low cardinality makes no sense. MySQL uses indexes only when it's faster than having to do full table scan. Now, if you could include the output of EXPLAIN, that would help us analyze everything that's wrong.

Comment: Your indexes look fine for the queries.  Perhaps the query load/locking of the writes is interfering with the query at times.

Comment: @N.B. I have edited my question to include the output of EXPLAIN statement. Can you help to explain why indexes with low cardinality does not make sense? And, why forcing an index with low cardinality makes no sense? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! That's what I thought of, too. Hence, we were planning to use InnoDB for that table but were having trouble with the speed of writing.

Answer (score 0):

The index `device_sn` (`device_sn`,`data`,`dt`) is good. MySQL should use it without need to do any FORCE INDEX. You can verify it by running "explain select ..."

However, your table is MyISAM, which is only supports table level locks. If the table is heavily write it may be slow. I would suggest converting it to InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to convert to InnoDB before but somehow it causes the write to be very slow. Is there a way to speed up InnoDB write? I tried `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` set to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll provide info that I know and this might not answer your question but could provide some insight.

There exits certain differences between InnoDB and MyISAM. Forget about full text indexing or spatial indexes, the huge difference is in how they operate.

InnoDB has several great features compared to MyISAM.
First off, it can store the data set it works with in RAM. This is why database servers come with a lot of RAM - so that I/O operations could be done quick. For example, an index scan is faster if you have indexes in RAM rather than on HDD because finding data on HDD is several magnitudes slower than doing it in RAM. Same applies for full table scans.
The variable that controls this when using InnoDB is called `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. By default it's 8 MB if I am not mistaken. I personally set this value high, sometimes even up to 90% of available RAM. Usually, when this value is optimized - a lot of people experience incredible speed gains.

The other thing is that InnoDB is a transactional engine. That means it will tell you that a write to disk succeeded or failed and that will be 100% correct. MyISAM won't do that because it doesn't force OS to force HDD to commit data permanently. That's why sometimes records are lost when using MyISAM, it thinks data is written because OS said it was when in reality OS tried to optimize the write and HDD might lose buffer data, thus not writing it down. OS tries to optimize the write operation and uses HDD's buffers to store larger chunks of data and then it flushes it in a single I/O. What happens then is that you don't have control over *how* data is being written.
With InnoDB you can start a transaction, execute say 100 INSERT queries and then commit. That will effectively force the hard drive to flush all 100 queries at once, using 1 I/O. If each INSERT is 4 KB long, 100 of them is 400 KB. That means you'll utilize 400kb of your disk's bandwith with 1 I/O operation and that remainder of I/O will be available for other uses. This is how inserts are being optimized.

Next are indexes with low cardinality - cardinality is a number of unique values in an indexed column. For primary key this value is 1. it's also the highest value. Indexes with low cardinality are columns where you have a few distinct values, such as `yes` or `no` or similar. If an index is too low in cardinality, MySQL will prefer a full table scan - it's MUCH quicker. Also, forcing an index that MySQL doesn't want to use could (and probably will) slow things down - this is because when using an indexed search, MySQL processes records one by one. When it does a table scan, it can read multiple records at once and avoid processing them. If those records were written sequentially on a mechanical disk, further optimizations are possible.

TL;DR:

- use InnoDB on a server where you can allocate sufficient RAM
- set the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` large enough so you can allocate more resources for faster querying
- use an SSD if possible
- try to wrap multiple INSERTs into transactions so you can better utilize your hard drive's bandwith and I/O
- avoid indexing columns that have low unique value count compared to row count - they just waste space (though there are exceptions to this)